# set background in code with javafx

Tags: java, image, background, resources, javafx

I am trying to implement a background image with the following code without CSS however it is not working for me.

below is the code, and the error

**Code**

```
Group root = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 1180); //1180, 650

String image = JavaFXApplication4.class.getClass().getResource("wallpaper4.jpg").toExternalForm();
root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-repeat: stretch; -fx-background-size: 650 1180;-fx-background-position: top left;");

System.out.println("path: " + image);

stage.setScene(scene);
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4.start(JavaFXApplication4.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:811)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:258)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

**location of the wallpaper**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. It should be

```
String image = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource("wallpaper4.jpg").toExternalForm();
```

Comment: Th program runs nuw, but withouth a background image, and the path i get is path: jar:file:/Users/ossama/NetBeansProjects/PrayerTime/dist/run692432172/JavaFXApplication4.jar!/javafxapplication4/wallpaper4.jpg

Comment: @Ossama, use a Pane (or its subclasses) as a root instead of Group.

Comment: still not working `Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 1180); //1180, 650
        
        String image = JavaFXApplication4.class.getResource("wallpaper4.jpg").toExternalForm();
        
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-repeat: stretch; -fx-background-size: 650 1180;-fx-background-position: top left;");
        System.out.println("path: " + image);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Prayer Time Display");`

Comment: @Ossama. Right click on the project in Netbeans and clean rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

'root' should be declared as a StackPane. Try this:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane()
```

Comment: StackPane root = new StackPane(); just to correct the previous comment